# Which Database is SQLEditor supposed to query on

Tags: dbeaver

DBeaver 6.2.1

Regularily, I want to perform an sql query on the database I am currently working on. Since there is no "query sql" in the context menu, I try to use the SQL Editor, which opens an editor window where I can write the sql I like. However, this does not work as expected. Actually, there is no information which Database the sql Editor is working on, and my expectation that it must be the one currently selected just proved to be wrong.

So 2 Questions:

1. What is the expected way to query sql on the currently selected Database in DBeaver
2. What Database is the SQL Editor defaultly working on and how can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What is the expected way to query sql on the currently selected Database in DBeaver

Use ANSI SQL standard queries. For example, I execute queries on Sybase using DBeaver as this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UserTable1
```

> What Database is the SQL Editor defaultly working on and how can I change this?

1. Menu Bar > Window > Database Navigator : This lists out all the schemas/databases on the connected server and the one highlighted in BOLD is the one DBeaver is connected to based on what is mentioned while creating connection.
2. You can activate/change/select Database/schema by pressing ctrl+0 to bring up "Active Catalog/Schema" option.

-- In 'thoughts'...

Comment: I noticed since the last Update to 6.3.3, which database is highlighted in the navigator doesn't affect the SQL Editor anymore, and the right click context menu is missing the previously present "select active schema" action. One has to use the dropdown in the top menu bar now.

Comment: 1. The question is rather meant as: Where do I insert this ANSI SQL standard query to perform the query on the currently selected database

Comment: @Ferenjito You will need to open SQL Editor to write queries. Look @ https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/SQL-Editor